# Server Side or Client Side Long Polling?

Tags: javascript, php, long-polling

What are best practices for `long polling`?

Currently what I have set up is `javascript` making an `xmlhttprequest` to a `server` with `PHP` running server side checking if there is anything new and return new content or no new content variable. Then client side will wait for `n` seconds after receiving the returned value before making another request.

But I'm seeing a lot online with a different approach, that if the `server` does not have anything new **don't** return just yet instead wait for `n` seconds and check again for new content until a certain number of attempts then return new content or no new content and the client side makes a new request right after receiving the returned value.

So with the above 2 which one would be the best approach to give less strain on a server or maybe conserve more server resources? My current setup or the 2nd setup? Or maybe a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your awesome nickname I would suggest a slightly different approach: **dead polling**

Comment: The first approach isn't long polling at all, it's just requesting data on an interval. If you're interval is long, say, 2-5 minutes or more, interval is better. If your interval is short, say, less than a minute, long-polling will be better.

Comment: @letiagoalves lolling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option isn't long-polling at all, it's just sending a request every n seconds. Long-polling means you send a request that stays open until a timeout is reached, or new data is available.

Long-polling is better than sending a request every n seconds because the data is closer to real-time without needing to send a request every *<less than 10>* seconds.

Typically on the server-side you would handle a long-polling request by using a sleep loop that repeatedly checks the db for new data with a short delay, say, 1 or two seconds. So, if you did it with a 2second delay and a 30 second timeout, you'll be hitting that database 15 times per user per 30 seconds.

Yes, long-polling can be resource intensive. You as the developer have to decide how much of the server's resources you can allocate to improve the user experience.

websockets is the go-to solution now days for chat systems because it bypasses this problem, allowing the server to contact the client(s) when there is a change rather than having n clients contacting the server every x seconds asking if something changed. It would normally work by having a "Post Message" command that the client calls when a new message is added by a client, that command would then broadcast the new message to all connected clients.

Comment: for a chat system would you still recommend long polling? I'm thinking a 10 second `sleep()` after an `if no new message` with a max of 3 times then return. would that be ok?

Comment: Sorry, i just updated my answer to be more clear. The advantage of long-polling is that you can get near-realtime results without having to send a request every second. Yes, using sleep() in a loop, looping 3 times checking for new messages would be an example of long-polling.

Comment: I personally would sleep for, say, 2 seconds, and loop 15 times resulting in a 30 second timeout.

Comment: So I guess less requests is better?

Comment: Long-polling is still resource intensive for the server as you can see (over 30 seconds, it will query the db up to 15 times per user using the app.) This is why most chat systems are using websockets instead with long-polling as a fallback.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. you have to decide whether you want to lean more toward a real-time feeling chat system, or a less-server resource intensive solution that gives a far less real-time feel.

Comment: I guess you can't have both unless you have google or facebook servers. thanks for the info very helpful! I'll adjust my code to long polling but I think the 2 second sleep with 15 loops is kinda overkill especially if you have a lot of users haha thanks again!

Comment: After your edit I think I'm gonna go for websockets.